# React child is changing parent props

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-props

Basically, I'm having trouble with the immutability principle, which somehow is being broken. The issue is: the components "PokerSection" are changing the props object "game" from this initial parent component in App.js.

Here's the order of the component's parents and child:

1º App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Poker game={poker} />
  );
};

export default App;
```

2º Poker

```
const Poker = ({ game }) => {
  return (
      <Slider {...sliderSettings}>
        <PokerSection game={game} />
        <PokerSection game={game} />
      </Slider>
  );
};

export default Eurogame;
```

3º PokerSection

```
const PokerSection = ({ game }) => {
  const [gameNumbers, setGameNumbers] = useState({
    mainNumbers: game.mainNumbers,
    starNumbers: game.starNumbers,
    numbersPerPlay: game.numbersPerPlay,
  });

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
    mainSelected: [],
    starsSelected: [],
  });

  //MAIN NUMBERS
  const handleMainNumbers = (number) => {
    const gameNumbersCopy = { ...gameNumbers };
    const checkSelected = selected.mainSelected.includes(number);
    /*  EXPLANATION:
       Check if the number has already been selected (checkSelected)
       -> NO (false): Add to the "mainSelected" list and change the key selected for the number in "gameNumbers" to true;
       -> YES (true): Remove from the "mainSelected" list and change the key selected for the number in "gameNumbers" to false; */

    /* FALSE */
    if (
      !checkSelected &&
      selected.mainSelected.length < game.numbersPerPlay["main"]
    ) {
      const selectedCopy = { ...selected };
      selectedCopy.mainSelected.push(number);
      setSelected(selectedCopy);
      const index = gameNumbersCopy.mainNumbers.findIndex(
        (objNumber) => objNumber["number"] === number
      );
      gameNumbersCopy.mainNumbers[index].selected = true;
      setGameNumbers(gameNumbersCopy);

      /*  TRUE */
    } else if (checkSelected) {
      const selectedCopy = { ...selected };
      const filteredNumbers = selectedCopy.mainSelected.filter(
        (num) => num !== number
      );
      selectedCopy.mainSelected = filteredNumbers;
      setSelected(selectedCopy);
      const index = gameNumbersCopy.mainNumbers.findIndex(
        (objNumber) => objNumber["number"] === number
      );
      gameNumbersCopy.mainNumbers[index].selected = false;
      setGameNumbers(gameNumbersCopy);
    }
  };
  //STAR NUMBERS
  const handleStarNumbers = (number) => {
    const gameNumbersCopy = { ...gameNumbers };
    const checkSelected = selected.starsSelected.includes(number);
    if (
      !checkSelected &&
      selected.starsSelected.length < game.numbersPerPlay["stars"]
    ) {
      const selectedCopy = { ...selected };
      selectedCopy.starsSelected.push(number);
      setSelected(selectedCopy);
      const index = gameNumbersCopy.starNumbers.findIndex(
        (objNumber) => objNumber["number"] === number
      );
      gameNumbersCopy.starNumbers[index].selected = true;
      setGameNumbers(gameNumbersCopy);

      /*  TRUE */
    } else if (checkSelected) {
      const selectedCopy = { ...selected };
      const filteredNumbers = selectedCopy.starsSelected.filter(
        (num) => num !== number
      );
      selectedCopy.starsSelected = filteredNumbers;
      setSelected(selectedCopy);
      const index = gameNumbersCopy.starNumbers.findIndex(
        (objNumber) => objNumber["number"] === number
      );
      gameNumbersCopy.starNumbers[index].selected = false;
      setGameNumbers(gameNumbersCopy);
    }
  };
 
  return (
    <div className="eurocard">
      <h5>main numbers</h5>
      <div className="eurocard-main-numbers">
        {gameNumbers.mainNumbers.map((objNumber) => (
          <div
            key={objNumber["number"]}
            onClick={() => handleMainNumbers(objNumber["number"])}
          >
            {objNumber["number"]}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <h5>star numbers</h5>
      <div className="eurocard-star-numbers">
        {gameNumbers.starNumbers.map((objNumber) => (
          <div
            key={objNumber["number"]}
            onClick={() => handleStarNumbers(objNumber["number"])}
            {objNumber["number"]}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokerSection;
```

Can you help me understand this please? :)
Thanks in advance and stay safe!

Comment: Can I ask what changes should happen in PokerSection? and why you are using two `<PokerSection game={game} />` with the same props?

Comment: The best option you can add the set state function in app.js and pass throw props and after changing the state value you can pass the updated object app.js to the child components.

Comment: PokerSection are cards where you should be able to select numbers, (like a lottery and not so much like a Poker game). So each card should have access to the game object and then make their own changes internally in their states, otherwise, they change all at the same time (which is what's happening)

Comment: The spread syntax `...obj/arr` is only a shallow copy. So if you have nested objects or arrays, they will still reference the nested properties from props.

Comment: So its pieces like this `gameNumbersCopy.mainNumbers[index].selected = true;` that are not updating the copy, but the original nested property. You'll just need to make a deep copy of the `game` prop, and the problem will go away.

Comment: I've thought of that, but wasn't aware of nested objects. Thank you so much Brian :) Do you have any suggestions of how I could solve this issue? I saw that lodash has those features, I'll read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brian Thompson, I've managed to solve the issue. In order to guarantee the immutability of nested objects and arrays, I've used **lodash, ._cloneDeep(value)** and it worked perfectly. Thanks to everyone for your time! Happy coding :)